# How to concatenate 2 or more strings as one inside a string array in Java?

Tags: java, android

I'd like to concatenate 2 or more consecutive strings into one string in an array according to two variables `x` and `y` meaning that starting from the **x:th** element, concatenate, until we have concatenated **y** elements. For example, if an Array 'A' has elements as:

```
A = {"europe", "france", "germany", "america"};
x=2;y=2;
//Here, I want to concatenate france and germany as :
A = {"europe", "france germany", "america"};
//Or 
x=2,y=3;

A= {"europe", "france germany america"};
```

Like this. Anyone know How This can be done without complex programming?

Comment: I don't understand how the `x` and `y` values translate into various concatenations.

Comment: Yeah that's the same thing I was wondering

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If `x=2,y=2`, that means starting from the **2** nd element, concatenate, until we have concatenated **2** elements

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen in the array, i want particular CONSECUTIVE words to be concatenated (based on the requirement, the starting word and the number of words to be concatenated changes). Thats why x(first word location in the array) and y(no. Of words to be concatenated) are needed. I was hoping they could be used in a for loop sorts.

Comment: @Sweeper  yes! Thats right! Thank you for explaining this simply :)

Comment: 1) create an array of the right length. 2) copy the array elements before and after into the array, using `System.arraycopy`. 3) concatenate the elements in the middle using `String.join`.

Comment: Thank you all for your enthusiastic answers. I really appreciate it. I was wondering if it’s possible to do the concatenation without creating another array. Pardon me if I’m being greedy, but the app I’m working requires a lot of processing speed and memory. This concatenation may be recursive for each array it is fed . So I’m trying to save as much as I can, where I can.

Comment: @AndyTurner You could post that as answer, as it is probably the most efficient way to do this :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the most concise way is:

1. Construct an array of the right size:

   ```
   String[] result = new String[A.length - (y-1)];
   ```
2. Copy the start and the end of the array using `System.arraycopy`:

   ```
   System.arraycopy(A, 0, result, 0, x-1);
   System.arraycopy(A, x+y-1, result, x+1, A.length-(x+1));
   ```
3. Build the concatenated string:

   ```
   result[x-1] = String.join(" ", Arrays.asList(A).subList(x-1, x-1+y));
   ```

(Note: out by one errors may be present, owing to the date of writing)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working script, though I don't know how simple you would consider it to be.  The algorithm is to simply walk down the input array, copying over strings to the output, until we reach the first entry as determined by the `x` value.  Then, we concatenate the `y` number of terms to a single string.  Finally, we finish by copying over the remaining terms one-by-one.

```
public static String[] concatenate(String[] input, int x, int y) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // just copy over values less than start of x range
    for (int i=0; i < x-1; ++i) {
        list.add(input[i]);
    }

    // concatenate y values into a single string
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    for (int i=0; i < y; ++i) {
        if (i > 0) sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(input[x-1+i]);
    }
    list.add(sb.toString());

    // copy over remaining values
    for (int i=x+y-1; i < input.length; ++i) {
        list.add(input[i]);
    }
    String[] output = new String[list.size()];
    output = list.toArray(output);

    return output;
}

String[] input = new String[] {"europe", "france", "germany", "america"};
int x = 2;
int y = 3;
String[] output = concatenate(input, x, y);
for (String str : output) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very straightforward procedural approach:

```
private static ArrayList<String> concatenate(String[] strings, int x, int y) {
    ArrayList<String> retVal = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int count = y;
    boolean concatenated = false;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < strings.length ; i++) {
        if (i < x - 1 || concatenated) {
            retVal.add(strings[i]);
        } else {
            builder.append(" ");
            builder.append(strings[i]);
            count--;
            if (count == 0) {
                retVal.add(builder.toString());
                concatenated = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Explanation:

- For each element in the inout array:
- Add the element to the return value if we haven't reached the `x - 1` index **or** we have finished concatenating.
- If we reached `x - 1` and not finished concatenating, add the element to the string builder.
- If we finished concatenating (indicated by `count == 0`), add the concatenated string to the return value.

Answer (score 1):

It should be done using a for loop and keeping tract of indices

```
String[] A = {"europe", "france", "germany", "america"};

String[] new_Array;
// your code goes here
int x=2,y=3;
int start_concat = x-1 ; // to account for array index

int stop_concat = start_concat+y;

new_Array = new String[A.length-y + 1];

for(int i=0; i<=start_concat; i++){   
     new_Array[i] = A[i];
}

for(int i = start_concat+1 ; i<stop_concat; i++){
    new_Array[start_concat] = new_Array[start_concat] + A[i];
}

for(int i =start_concat+1, j=stop_concat ; i< new_Array.length;i++,j++){
    new_Array[i] = A[j];
}

for(int i=0; i<new_Array.length; i++){
    System.out.println(new_Array[i]);
}
```

[See my snippet on ideone](https://ideone.com/3cH8cT)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `List` API we can leverage the [subList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) method as well as the [addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-int-java.util.Collection-) method to modify a particular section of a list and insert elements into a list at the specified position.

Along with that, we utilise the String [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method to remove the redundant string representation of a list and finally convert the accumulator list into an array of strings.

```
public static String[] concatElements(String[] elements, int start, int count){

       List<String>  accumulator = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(elements));
       List<String> subList = new ArrayList<>(accumulator.subList(--start, start + count));
       accumulator.removeAll(subList);

       String concatenatedElements = subList.toString()
                      .replace(",", "")
                      .replace("[","")
                      .replace("]", "");

       subList = Collections.singletonList(concatenatedElements);
       accumulator.addAll(start, subList);
       String[] resultSet = new String[accumulator.size()];

       for (int i = 0; i < accumulator.size(); i++) {
            resultSet [i] = accumulator.get(i);
       }
       return resultSet;
}
```

calling it like so:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(concatElements(array, 2, 2)));
```

will produce:

```
[europe, france germany, america]
```

and calling it like so:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(concatElements(array, 2, 3)));
```

will produce:

```
[europe, france germany america]
```

As is, there is no validation for the parameter `start` and `count` but I leave that as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 1):

Possible with Lists.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String arr []= {"europe", "france", "germany", "america"};
    int from =1;
    int toAdd =3;
    int len = arr.length;

    if(from+toAdd>len){
        //show error
        return ;
    }
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
    List<String> concatList = list.subList(from, from+toAdd);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String st: concatList){
        sb.append(st).append(" ");
    }
    List<String>outList = new ArrayList<>(list.subList(0, from));
    outList.add(sb.toString());
    if(from+toAdd<len-1){
        outList.addAll(list.subList(from+toAdd, list.size()-1));
    }
    System.out.println(outList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate `Strings` in `Android` we can use `TextUtils.copyOfRange()` class. For the rest we can go with `System.arraycopy()` method to avoid loops:

```
public static String[] concatenate(String[] input,
                                   int from, // starts from 0 position
                                   int number){
    String[] res = new String[input.length - number + 1];

    int to = from + number;

    System.arraycopy(input, 0, res, 0, from);

    String[] sub = Arrays.copyOfRange(input, from, to);
    String joined = TextUtils.join(" ", sub);
    res[from] = joined;

    System.arraycopy(input, to, res, from + 1, input.length - to);

    return res;
}
```

Comment: I think that’s a good idea to copy just the strings to be concatinated to another array and add concatenated string back to the original array. But though this method doesn’t use any loops, it uses extra string arrays. I guess what I need isn’t possible unless the elements of an array can be deleted completely(not just making them null).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using the `java.util.stream` library:

This uses `IntStream.range` to decide the new size of the output List, and to generate `int`s representing indexes in the output sequence.

Then `.mapToObj` is used for each output index to decide what to put in each respective position (output only has a single index for the joined strings).

There are essentially 3 possibilities for the output - which are decided by the `getOrMergeData` method:

- Before index of the joined strings - use `data[index]`
- After index of the joined strings - use `data[index + count - 1]`
- At index of the joined strings - use `Arrays.copyOfRange` and `string.Join` to join the strings which need to be merged together.

[Click for Running Example:](https://ideone.com/H7TRSn)

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] data = {"europe", "france", "germany", "america"};
    int startIndex = 1;
    int count = 2;
    int newSize = data.length - count + 1;

    List<String> output =
        IntStream.range(0, newSize)
                 .mapToObj(n -> Main.getOrJoin(data, startIndex, count, n))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (String s : output) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }

  private static String getOrJoin(String[] data, int joinIndex, int count, int index) {
    if (index < joinIndex) return data[index];
    else if (index > joinIndex) return data[index + count - 1];
    else {
        String[] dataToJoin = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, joinIndex, joinIndex + count);
        return String.join(" ", dataToJoin);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
europe
france germany
america
```

Comment: Maybe it’s just my java knowledge level, but this looks kinda complicated 